# Find shortest path of fixed hops between two node in a graph

Tags: algorithm, graph, fixed

if G = {V,E} is an undirected, connected, unweighted graph, and v is source vertex and u is destination vertex, I need to find shortest path between them. The problem is, I'm only allowed to move at fixed hops of size k. For example, if k = 3, reachable vertices from some vertex v are all the vertices that there exists a path of length 3 between them that doesn't traverse on the same edge twice. Each hop from v to u mustn't step on the same edge twice. However, a sequence of hops can move on the same edge several times.
So far I've tried several approaches without any success, but I have a feeling that there's dynamic programming involved. Any ideas?

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, it seems like you need to generate a new graph with the given k and then apply Dijkstra's. Does this help?

Answer (score 1):

One solution would be to create the graph `G' = {V,E'}` with the same vertex set as `G` but with the edge set consisting of the set of hops in the original graph, then using Dykstra's algorithm on `G'`.